# How do I remove duplicate objects from two separate ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist, comparison

Before beginning, I think that this question has a very simple answer that I'm just overlooking. I figured a few more eyes on the question at hand will be able to point out my problem fairly quickly.

I have two ArrayLists that I want to compare and remove duplicates from each of them. The first `ArrayList` is an `ArrayList` of older information where as the second `ArrayList` contains the new information.

Like so

```
ArrayList<Person> contactList = new ArrayList();
contactList.add(new Person("Bob");
contactList.add(new Person("Jake");
contactList.add(new Person("Joe");
ontactList.add(new Person("Rob");

ArrayList<Person> updatedContactList = new ArrayList();
updatedContactList.add(new Person("Bob");
updatedContactList.add(new Person("Jake");
updatedContactList.add(new Person("Joe");
updatedContactList.add(new Person("Phil");
```

My `Person` class is very simple, created solely for this example

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person(String a_name) {
        name = a_name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

So, using the above examples, I want to remove all duplicates. I'm trying keep it to just the two ArrayLists if possible, but am willing to do a deep clone of one of the ArrayLists if I have to.

So I want the resulting `ArrayList` to have the following information in it once the comparison is done

```
contactList           //removed Person
    - Rob

updatedContactList    //new Person
    - Phil
```

Here is the code I've put together

```
for(int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < updatedContactList.size(); j++) {

        if(contactList.get(i).getName().equals(updatedContactList.get(j).getName())) {
            //removed friends                    
            contactList.remove(contactList.get(i));

            //new friends ---- only one at a time works
            //updatedContactList.remove(updatedContactList.get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm only able to remove a Person from one of the ArrayLists in the above loop otherwise I get incorrect results.

So my question is, is there an easy way to remove the duplicated elements from both ArrayLists? If so, how do I go about it.

I realize that I could probably deep clone the updated `ArrayList` and just remove the objects from that one, but I'm wondering if there is a way without having to clone it.

I also realize that I could just stuff all the elements into a Set and it would remove the duplicates, but I want to keep the 'removed' and 'new' Person objects separate.

Comment: I assume that the individual lists will not have duplicates, correct?

Comment: @arshajii Once the comparison is done, each list should contain no duplicates between the two of them. One ArrayList will contain the `Person`(s) removed and the other ArrayList will contain only new `Person` objects.

Comment: I mean before-hand, before anything is done to the two lists. You cannot, for instance, have two `Bob`s in `contactList`, right?

Comment: @arshajii Correct. Sorry for the confusion. There will never be two of the same Person.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you really have is not lists, but sets: model both the old and the new contacts as a `Set`. Also implement `equals` and `hashCode` for your `Person` class to ensure proper operation.

Once you have that, you'll be able to write one-liners to calculate the set differences (which is what you need):

```
final Set<Person> contactsBackup = new HashSet<>(contacts);
contacts.removeAll(updatedContacts);
updatedContacts.removeAll(contactsBackup);
```

Note that this involves making one more copy, but it is not a deep copy—only references are copied. This is a very leightweight operation and you should not worry about its impact.

If, for some reason not at all obvious to me, you really need lists, the same code will work for them, too (`List` also defines `removeAll`), but you will have to live with O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity this operation entails for lists.

Comment: +1. The runtime of `List#removeAll(Collection)` actually depends of the type of collection passed as parameter. Your statement is true for `list.removeAll(otherList);`. Following would be `O(n)`: `list.removeAll(hashset);`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik This seems like a nice simple way to do it (as does jLordo's method), but what happens if I want my lists sorted? For instance, when I parse them out of the xml they come in alphabetically. But if I later decide I want them sorted by some different information in them, will it be a problem once they are a set?

Comment: @jlordo Well, I haven't opposed your statement at all :) But I caught an error in my comment so I deleted it. I couldn't keep the code verbatim.

Comment: @WilliamShatner You can use a `TreeSet` with a different `Comparator` for each sort order. Look at guava, they have a whole mini-DSL for implementing comparators just by calling some API methods. Actually, I may be wrong about that---it would need reflection. But I'm pretty sure LambdaJ does it.

Answer (score 3):

Override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your `Person` class and simply do:

```
Set<Person> temp = new HashSet<>(contactList);
contactList.removeAll(updatedContactList);
updatedContactList.removeAll(temp);
temp.clear(); // not necessary if this code is in a method
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? I assume for `equals()` I would do what I've done above (correct me if I'm wrong). I've never overridden `hashCode()` before. What would I do in my overridden `hashCode()` method?

Comment: Are you using eclipse? If so, click `Source --> Generate hashCode() and equals()`

Comment: Netbeans 7.1 (jdk is still at 6)

Comment: You can just google for "implementing hashcode". I wouldn't recommend generating code you don't understand. Code generation should only be a keystroke-saver.

Comment: BTW your final line, `temp.clear()` is not necessary. `temp` is a local variable, anyway, so this would just add a performance overhead.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: yeah, I wasn't clear about that. Assuming the reference to temp is in scope longer, I suggested `clear`ing it to make the `Person`s that are not needed anymore eligible for gc.

Comment: If OP had more processing to do in the same method, which involved more copying, then `clear` could come in handy. Then again, if GC-ing was really needed, I'd prefer a simple `temp = null;`. Simpler, faster, and even slightly more effective.

Comment: Seeing as I will have to read up on `hashCode()` a bit before I can try this solution, I will go with Marko's solution but give you an upvote while I read into it a bit. Btw thanks for the new info jlordo and marko!

Comment: @WilliamShatner: You'll need `equals()` and `hashCode()` in Marko's solution as well ;)

Comment: I wasn't aware of that! But I guess that makes sense, now that I think about it a bit. I was hoping that comparing it would be simple :/ Looks like I have quite a bit of reading to do!

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Set` and `addAll` from both the `ArrayLists`.

```
Set<Person> set = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: The problem with this is that they would then be combined. At the end of my question, I (poorly) stated that I would like them to be in separate containers.

Answer (score 2):

This is a one line elegant solution making use of the Java 8 capabilities

```
public static final <T> void removeCommonEntries(Collection<T> a, Collection<T> b){
        b.removeIf(i -> a.remove(i));
}
```

I use to put this solution in a custom `CollectionUtils`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case use Set and not List (this is used if you are getting data from DB using say Hibernate) if possible. Then you can override equals and hashcode method in person class so that while adding required comparisons can be made and duplicates can be taken out. LinkedHashSet can be used as Lists can become slow as data in it grows.